# Why can I ping machines using the .local suffix, but not without?

Tags: networking, dns, ping, hostname

My local network uses a .lan suffix. I would rather not use any suffix at all, but apparently pfSense doesn't permit this.

I am running Windows, MacOS and Linux systems on this lan. Most of my machines can be pinged by name only (e.g. "ping nas"), or with the suffix (e.g. "ping nas.lan"). One or two of them, however (generally Debian systems) cannot be pinged by name unless I use the .local suffix: "ping nas-mirror.local".

I don't understand why this is. My resolv.conf contains "search lan", my hostname file contains "nas-mirror.lan", and I have installed winbind.

I don't want to use the .local suffix. I want to use no suffix at all - or, failing that, the .lan suffix. Why doesn't this work, and what can I do about it?

(Please note I am not a networking expert.)

Comment: Just an idea: it is possible that the `hostname` of the machine is `nas-mirror.local` (with included the `.local`) and the `domainname` is `(none)`. Try those two commands on that machine (`hostname` and `domainname`).  You can also try with `ping nas-mirror.local.local`, yes 2 times from another computer.

Comment: @hastur: It seems you're quite correct. I assume 'local' is merely a default that applies in the absence of a configured domainname. Where is the domainname stored, for `domainname` to pull from? What file does it live in? Thanks.

Comment: Start with `hostname` and `domainname` (those are two commands). You can start to  see in `/etc/hostname` for the hostname and  in `/etc/hosts`. With `man hostname` and `/bin/domainname --help` more informations...  if you have `domainname` -> `(none)` and `hostname -a` -> nome.local` probably you have not set the domain name...

Comment: @hastur: Yes, I know all that. But I'd like to know what actual file `domainname` is checking.

Comment: No answer to this?

Comment: just more fyi - `/bin/domainname` is simply a symbolic link (on Debian/Ubuntu anyway) to `/bin/hostname`. If your `domainname` command is linked back to `/bin/hostname`, you can use same flags/arguments: `hostname -d` will give you the current "domain name". Which should be the same as `domainname -d`. You may get `(none)`, otherwise if you omit all flags using just `domainame`.